# Fraction or percentage regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning regular expression as part of my Java course. Now I know sometimes the best use of regex is to *not* use regex at all. But since I have to use it for this course and learn it, I figure I might as well learn it *properly*.

I am matching `(##/##)` or `(##)` where `#` is a number `0-9`. All white space is ignored (except for in between the digits `##`). In context, I'm matching a fraction `(10/20)` or a percentage `(50)`.

For example `(  ##   / ##    )` and `(   ## )` are valid. `(# #/#  #)` and `(#  #)` are not.

**Code / Explanation:**

```regex
(?:[(])(?:[ ]*)?([\d][\d])(?:[ ]*)?(?:[\/])?(?:[ ]*)?([\d][\d])?(?:[ ]*)?(?:[)])
```

---

```
(?:[(])          Beginning parathensis (
(?:[ ]*)?        All white space
([\d][\d])       Two digits for the first number ##
(?:[ ]*)?        All white space
(?:[\/])?        Forward slash /
(?:[ ]*)?        All white space
([\d][\d])?      Two digits for the second number ##
(?:[ ]*)?        All white space
(?:[)])          Closing parathensis )
```

**[Try it online](http://regexr.com/3deob)**

Example usage in Java:

```java
String regex = "(?:[(])(?:[ ]*)?([\\d][\\d])(?:[ ]*)?(?:[\\/])?(?:[ ]*)?([\\d][\\d])?(?:[ ]*)?(?:[)])";
String test = "(20/50)";

if (test.matches(regex)) { // true
    System.out.println("Valid.");
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid.");
}
```

Everything is setup using non-capture groups, except for the two digits. This is so I can [reference the capture groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-) in my code (and simply check if group 2 is null before trying to use it, indicating `(##)` not `(##/##)`).

This is basically my first time writing regex from complete scratch. Some questions are:

- Should I be wrapping everything in `[ ]` even when they can be left out? i.e. `(?: *)` instead of `(?:[ ]*)`.
- Is my use of non-capture groups the right way to do things (feels verbose to me)?

Generally, what can I improve on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex accepts `(20/)` as valid input, and I suspect that you didn't intend to consider it valid.

Your regex rejects one-digit numbers.  If that is intentional, you might want to write a comment about it in the code.

---

As you suspected, this is a very "noisy" regex — nearly unreadable.  This expression would do the job:

```
String regex = "\\( *(\\d{2}) *(?:/ *(\\d{2}) *)?\\)";
```

There is no need to wrap everything in `[ ]`.  In this particular problem, there aren't even any character classes to speak of.  The only place where the square brackets *might* be justified is as a hack to formulate the expression with fewer backslashes:

```
String regex = "[(] *(\\d{2}) *(?:/ *(\\d{2}) *)?[)]";
```

In `(?:[ ]*)?`, the square brackets are pointless.  The `?` is redundant with `*`.  So, you can just write a space followed by `*`.

In `([\d][\d])`, the square brackets are pointless, and I would slightly prefer seeing `(\d{2})` to `(\d\d)`, since it can more easily be modified to accommodate different numbers of digits.

You might want to consider naming the capture groups for clarity:

```
String regex = "\\( *(?<numerator>\\d{2}) *(?:/ *(?<denominator>\\d{2}) *)?\\)";
```